# Passing the properties of an object as props Vuejs

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2

hi everyone,
                                    I have some confusion. I have two component ( child and parent component) and I pass the properties of an object as props

```
<child :child-data="abc" ></child>
Vue.component('childComponent', {
props: ['childData'],
 data: function(){
    return {
        count:this.childData,// recommend use Vue.util.extend
    }
 },
});
```

Vue will recursively convert "data" properties of childComponent into getter/setters to make it “reactive”.
So why doesn't it automatic bind data to the template? I read some recommend use Vue.util.extend. Why Vue.util.extend?

**UPDATE**

my example: 
https://jsfiddle.net/hoanghung1995/xncs5qpd/56/

when i set default value of parentData ,childDataA will display it. But when i use v-model to override parentData then childDataA not “reactive”. I must use "watch" to  override "data" ,similar to childDataB

Vue.util.extend example: https://jsfiddle.net/sm4kx7p9/3/

Why do Vue.util.extend work fine but not use "watch"?,

Comment: Why don't you use `childPropsA` directly?. `childPropsA`  is reactive right. If some modification needed then computed properties can be used.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To explain what is actually happening in the background, [Linus Borg has as excellent answer for your question](https://forum.vuejs.org/t/data-properties-based-on-props-are-not-re-evaluated-when-props-change/21085/2). To summarize his answer, the reason why your approach doesn't work is being `data` is a computed property while `props` are being passed in as primitive types. In other words, `data` makes a **copy** of your props (instead of passing by reference).

Another way to bypass this is to declare your childData as computed properties instead of data, i.e.:

```
computed: {
    childDataA() {
        return this.childPropsA;
    },
    childDataB() {
        return this.childPropsB;
    }
}
```

The reason why using `computed` works is because the computed properties now watches changes to their dependencies.

A proof-of-concept example based on your original fiddle:

```js
Vue.component('child', {
  props: ['childPropsA', 'childPropsB'],
  template: "#sub",
  computed: {
    childDataA() {
      return this.childPropsA;
    },
    childDataB() {
      return this.childPropsB;
    }
  }
});
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    parentData: '123'
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.16/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  parentData:{{parentData}}<br>
  <input type="text" v-model="parentData">
  <child :child-props-a="parentData" :child-props-b="parentData"></child>
</div>
<template id="sub">
  <div>
    <p> 1- {{ childDataA }}</p> 
    <p> 2- {{ childDataB }}</p> 
    </div>
</template>
```

The approach above is functionally identical to the `data` + `watch` approach, but I find it rather cumbersome and adds unnecessary verbosity to your code:

```
data: function() {
    return {
      childDataA: this.childPropsA,
      childDataB: this.childPropsB
    };
  },
  watch: {
    childPropsA() {
      this.childDataA = this.childPropsA;
    },
    childPropsB() {
      this.childDataB = this.childPropsB;
    }
  }
```

```js
Vue.component('child', {
  props: ['childPropsA', 'childPropsB'],
  template: "#sub",
  data: function() {
    return {
      childDataA: this.childPropsA,
      childDataB: this.childPropsB
    };
  },
  watch: {
    childPropsA() {
      this.childDataA = this.childPropsA;
    },
    childPropsB() {
      this.childDataB = this.childPropsB;
    }
  }
});
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    parentData: '123'
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.16/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  parentData:{{parentData}}<br>
  <input type="text" v-model="parentData">
  <child :child-props-a="parentData" :child-props-b="parentData"></child>
</div>
<template id="sub">
  <div>
    <p> 1- {{ childDataA }}</p> 
    <p> 2- {{ childDataB }}</p> 
    </div>
</template>
```

Comment: sorry if I bother you, I hope you help me again. I read Linus Borg's article , "your props’ values are primitives - strings, numbers, booleans" , " only object properties and arrays can be" 
I do not know much  primitive types and computed property. If computed property is only simple array or object then i can pass props an array or a object and they will be computed property, right?. Can you share to me some document about them? 
thank you so much

Answer (score 0):

Watch does only watch properties which are indeed reactive. Passing objects doesn`t makes their properties reactive. Just pass the properties that you want as props. 
With Vue.util.extend you force the property to be reactive in this instance.